# Authentication window opens and closes before loading in Cisco AnyConnect

Tags: cisco

I'm having difficulties resolving an issue that has been occurring with Cisco AnyConnect. The login is successful, but it closes after the authentication window. I don't have much knowledge, but I have installed several libraries and followed various tutorials without success. I'm using version 22, but I also tested version 23 on another Linux distribution in a virtual machine, and the same issue occurred. I also tried using OpenConnect, although I'm not sure if it's compatible with the company's login method. There was communication, but it was interrupted due to an SSO failure. Is anyone else experiencing this error? I believe it may be some sort of blocking by the company on Linux because I can use it without any problems on Windows and even on Android